# Calling an Ansible script inside of a ansible script and/or within a Loop module

Tags: windows, ansible, rhel

Context:

I am trying to deploy an IDAM solution. In order to do that specific things need to be installed in a certain order.

How I am currently doing it:

I have a variables file that looks like `vars/main.yml`:

```
EPM: 
  list_of_packages: 
    - package1.msi 
    - package2.msi 
    - package3.msi 
    - package4.msi
```

Now this method 1 works if I do:

`win_package:
  path: C:\path\{{ item }}
  arguments: /qn /norestart
loop: "{{ EPM['list_of_packages'] }}`

The problem is Package1 doesn't properly install. In order to get Package1 installed I needed to create a separate Ansible script that executes a bunch of .SQL scripts. This script, for the sake of this example is called: `epm_sql_scripts.yml`

This script loops through a bunch of .SQL scripts with the `loop` module and `psiexec` module.

It looks similar to method 1 script.

Is there a way I can call the `epm_sql_scripts.yml` from the method 1 script and/or from the `vars/main.yml file`?

Answer (score 0):

I understand where you were heading but ansible wont allow you to do that. You cannot nest playbooks like your example.
Other important point is that, if you choose to use `import_tasks`  the playbook imported must contain only tasks.

Comment: This is ultimately what I ended up doing. Not ideal. Especially, since in my actual case it isn't package 1 it's package 3 and they need to be installed in a correct order. So I am now thinking about just breaking everything into separate tasks. A loop would have been the most efficient way of doing it, but unfortunately it's making for some sloppy code.